# How can I list all vhosts in nginx

Tags: linux, shell, nginx

Is there a command that will list all vhosts or servers running under nginx on CentOS? I would like to pipe the results to a text file for reporting purposes.

I'm looking for something similar to this command that I use for Apache:

apachectl -S 2>&1 | grep 'port 80'

Comment: That depends on what you call `vhost`. Nginx's server block could match any number of domains. Maybe you want to list all server blocks?

Comment: Yes, server blocks would work. Probably those for port 80. The point is to list all websites in order to generate billing for hosting.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Update:**
Thanks to @Putnik for pointing out an easier way (but I prefer only listing sites-enabled):

```
grep server_name /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* -RiI
```

---

**Old Post:**

Try something like this:

```
find /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 egrep '^(\s|\t)*server_name'
```

Comment: That works, except I don't have a sites-enabled folder so I dropped that portion.

Comment: If you're hosting thousands of websites, chances are that some of your confs will have multiple domains separated by newlines. This answer will not capture those. See the answer below by Anthony Briggs which is the most complete.

Comment: Can someone clarify what the `RiI` options are doing?

Comment: -R: recursive, -i: ignore case, -I: ignore binary files

Comment: To my knowledge `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` is created on Debian based systems (to mimic Apache). This is an elegant solution but not generic enough

Comment: This is 1) distribution dependant and 2) assumes the admin ships their servers with distribution defaults. It should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: This (obviously) doesn't account for entries being separated by newlines

Answer (score 150):

starting from version 1.9.2 you can do:

```
nginx -T
```

show complete nginx configuration

```
nginx -T | grep "server_name " #include the whitespace to exclude non relevant results
```

show you all server names

Comment: Much better answer, doesn't assume config directory structure, only shows what nginx is aware of. Thanks

Comment: Yap! That should be the green checked answer. Right in the context of the question. People tent to curry away some times!!

Comment: This needs the green tick.  And can be modified to include the current answer for lower Nginx versions.

Comment: true.. my sites directory is `/etc/nginx/sites.d/`. so the accepted answer does not work for me.

Comment: Note that you may need to pass `-p` also (e.g. on GitLab Omnibus: `/opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -p /var/opt/gitlab/nginx -T`)

Comment: This (obviously) doesn't account for entries being separated by newlines

Answer (score 35):

The answers so far will work, ***except*** if you have `server_name` directives running over multiple lines, then it'll silently fail. They also seem to be written for human consumption (picking up extra lines like `server_name_in_redirect off;`) so you can't include them in a script.

I have lots of virtual hosts, and wanted to use the output in a script (*sigh*), so here's something which is a lot longer, but should be robust enough for that purpose:

```
nginx -T | sed -r -e 's/[ \t]*$//' -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/^#.*$//' -e 's/[ \t]*#.*$//' -e '/^$/d' | \
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\([^;\{\}]\)\n/\1 /g' | \
grep -P 'server_name[ \t]' | grep -v '\$' | grep '\.' | \
sed -r -e 's/(\S)[ \t]+(\S)/\1\n\2/g' -e 's/[\t ]//g' -e 's/;//' -e 's/server_name//' | \
sort | uniq | xargs -L1
```

Since it's long and `\`-y, I'll include a quick explanation of each line.

1. Get nginx to print its entire configuration (so that we don't have to worry about which files to include) and sanitise it: remove leading and trailing space, comments (including trailing ones) and blank lines.
2. Every line that doesn't end with a semi-colon or curly brace should be continued, so we replace any `\n` without a preceding `;`, `{` or `}` with a space. This needs to use sed's weirdo `:a;N;$!ba;` grab the whole file trick, and some grouping so that we can put the last character back with `\1`, plus a bunch of extra backslashes for luck.
3. Now we can pull each `server_name` line, with some extra checks to remove nginx variables (`$foo`) and only include valid domains (ie not `localhost` and `_`).
4. Any tabs/spaces between words get turned into carriage returns, then we remove surplus spaces (just in case), semi-colons and the `server_name` part.
5. Finally sort it, uniqify it and use `xargs -L1` to remove the single blank line at the top.

Note that there are some bits in here which are *technically* doubling up, but I like to be as clear and robust as possible. Suggestions for improvement welcome, though.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. All of the others only grab domains on the same line as the "server_name" label. Most of my nginx confs have additional domains separated by newlines.

Comment: Does not work on macOS (`sed: 2: ":a;N;$!ba;s/\([^;\{\}]\ ...": unused label 'a;N;$!ba;s/\([^;\{\}]\)\n/\1 /g'`), but works perfectly on Linux. Seems to be the only working parser for my configs.

Comment: I get a couple of lines like 
`nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok`
and `nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`
in the output from this, so I made it
    `nginx -T 2> /dev/null | sed ...`
which redirects the error stream to /dev/null

Answer (score 18):

`grep server_name /etc/nginx/* -RiI`

Imho much faster to type than @Haubix's answer.
Add `|grep -v "#"` optionally

Comment: This was my intuitive approach originally. Btw I think you can lose `/*`, if you just put the directory name then it will search from that level down

Answer (score 7):

Beside all the other great solution, if you just need a simple list of all names one per line, like:

```
example.com
my.example.com
etc.com
```

Parse the config. Get all lines with `server_name`. Remove `server_name`. Finally put one domain per line.

```
sudo nginx -T | grep "server_name " | sed 's/.*server_name \(.*\);/\1/' | sed 's/ /\n/'
```

Comment: If `server_name` occurs in any other conf file (say, the one defining `log_format`), you'll get undesired match

Comment: Thank you! `sudo nginx -T | grep "server_name "` was enough for my case.

Answer (score 5):

[@anthony-briggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338862/anthony-briggs) is correct to point out that most other answers given here won't work if your `server_name ... ;` declarations are spread out across multiple lines.

However, if you can afford the luxury of having a `perl` interpreter at your disposal, you can shorten his solution to this oneliner:

```sh
nginx -T | perl -ln0777e '$,=$\; s/^\s*#.*\n//mg; print grep !$u{$_}++ && !m/^_$/, map m/(\S+)/g, m/\bserver_name\s++(.*?)\s*;/sg'
```

In chunks:

```sh
perl -l -n -0777 -e
```

`-l` : Make the `print` command terminate its output with a newline;

It also causes trailing newlines to be stripped from each input record as its read, but that doesn't bother us because we:

`-n -0777` : Slurp all input into `$_` in one go (one record);

`-e` : Simply executes the next argument as Perl source;

---

```perl
$, = $\ ;
```

Make the `print` command also output a newline between each of its arguments;

---

```perl
s/^\s*#.*\n//mg ;
```

Remove all comments;

Disregarding leading whitespace, comments are assumed to start and run through to the end of a line ( `.` does not match a newline here);

---

```perl
m/\bserver_name\s++(.*?)\s*;/sg
```

Produce everything between all `server_name ... ;` declarations (`.` *does* match newlines here);

---

... which are all `map`-ped to:

```perl
map m/(\S+)/g,
```

... that will leave only the consecutive non-whitespace chunks;

---

... which are then `grep`-ped for uniqueness and *not* being the special "`_`" server name,

```perl
grep !$u{$_}++ && !m/^_$/,
```

... and `print`-ed (unsorted).

Answer (score 2):

```
grep server_name /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* -RiI | grep -v "#" | awk -F ' ' ' { print $3 "\n" $4  "\n" $5 }' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list the domains one line at a time using the following

```
nginx_domains(){
    domains=`find /etc/nginx/ -type f -name "*.conf" -print0 | xargs -0 egrep '^(\s|\t)*server_name' | sed -r 's/(.*server_name\s*|;)//g'`
    for domain in $domains; do 
       echo $domain; 
    done
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on most systems, only the core configuration files end in `.conf`, plus it'll pull in configuration lines like `server_names_hash_bucket_size`