# How to idiomatically filter a list of hostnames by testing for (in)equality to a `lookup( 'dig', ... )` in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In order to find the hostnames out of a given list that do not (yet) resolve to the `inventory_hostname` ip-address, I have - with a little help from https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20470#issuecomment-443218563 - come up with this little "beauty":

```
---
- hosts: 'all'
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: 'Failed hosts :: {{ hosts_failed | list }}'

  vars:

    - hosts:
        - 'google.com'
        - 'hackaday.com'
        - 'etc.etc'

    - hosts_failed: |
        {% set failed = [] %}
        {% for host in hosts %}
        {%     if inventory_hostname != lookup( "dig", host ) %}
        {%         set _ = failed.append( host ) %}
        {%     endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ failed }}
```

This was after I first tried, and failed, to approach it with the much more idiomatic filters and tests of ansible/jinja2 templating, something like

```
{{ hosts | reject( "eq", ...  ) }}
```

I couldn't, however, figure out how to parameterise that such that I could fit in the `lookup( "dig", .... )` call in there properly...

I tried piping the `hosts` array through a `map` filter first, but that breaks because apparently, `lookup` isn't a filter to jinja2.

```
{{ hosts | map( "lookup", "dig" ) | ... }}
```

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError: no filter named 'lookup'

What I've got now, works; but it has proven to be a pretty fragile solution.  That is, the slightest careless change to the `hosts_failed` template definition appears to be able to change whether ansible/jinja interprets its outcome as the array that I want it to be or as a mere string (the `| list` in the `debug` task above will quickly reveal which).

The question therefore is, is there a simpler, better, cleaner, more robust way of doing this?

---

The background for wanting this is to assert for a list of hostnames [extracted from an `nginx -T` config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400933/how-can-i-list-all-vhosts-in-nginx/59071568#59071568), that they all resolve to the site under construction before provisioning a `certbot` SSL certificate for it, and if not, report the ones that don't.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do that using a looping task rather than some fancy templating solution.  E.g.:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    hosts:
      - google.com
      - myhost.example.com
      - hackaday.com
    addr: 192.168.1.13
  tasks:
    - name: "find hosts that don't map to {{ addr }}"
      set_fact:
        failed_hosts: "{{ failed_hosts|default([]) + [item] }}"
      when: addr != lookup("dig", item)
      loop: "{{ hosts }}"

    - debug:
        var: failed_hosts
```

Which will produce output like this:

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [find hosts that don't map to 192.168.1.13] ******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=google.com)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=myhost.example.com) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=hackaday.com)

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "failed_hosts": [
        "google.com",
        "hackaday.com"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Here I'm running the task on `localhost` and setting the target address explicitly, but that's partly because I'm not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish. If necessary, we could certainly re-jigger this solution if you can clarify your question a bit.

Comment: I was under the impression that contrary to variables one couldn't change facts once they're set, but if that _does_ work, yes the looping task at least will be a more robust way of doing it.

Comment: The list of hostnames has been [extracted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400933/how-can-i-list-all-vhosts-in-nginx/59071568#59071568) from an `nginx -T` config, the goal being to assert that they all resolve to the host under construction before provisioning a `certbot` SSL certificate for it, and if not, report the ones that don't.

Comment: Note that you're **not** changing a fact here. You are repeatedly creating a new one that overrides the previous value.